# Multi-select from dropdown on custom field on User Story

Tags: rally

Currently I have a custom field on User Stories and Defects for our developer to tag what system was affected with their code change. Currently I only see a drop down, which is a single selection. Is there any way to give them the chance to multi-select options in the drop down? Or is there another object that would work better? Thanks in advance for all the great help I always get on here :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet to emulate a multi-select custom field is to use [Tags](http://www.rallydev.com/help/use-tags). If you are managing these stories and defects with a custom App you could restrict which Tags you show or allow them to choose from in that App.

Answer (score 0):

As Charles indicated, you probably want to try to use the MultiObjectPicker or the TagPicker, that extends it. If you want to stick with the ComboBox, then you can enable multi-selection by setting the "multiSelect" config field to "true".